# Using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client in Xamarin IOS application, not working when app in background

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

Using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client in Xamarin IOS application, when app is in background connection getting disconnected.and is not working . Any Suggestion

Comment: That's expected, because on a mobile device, your app is not running in the background, but suspended. It is rather complicated to work around that, https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/252239/do-ios-apps-run-in-the-background so you need to rethink why you need any background activities (most apps don't).

Comment: MSFT has a doc that covers iOS backgrounding: `Introduction to Backgrounding in iOS` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/backgrounding/introduction-to-backgrounding-in-ios

Comment: I have implelemented the iOS Backgrounding Techniques but after 30 seconds either it is crashing or app gets killed because if I open the app it open as a fresh\

Comment: Could you clarify which line cause the error or provide the crash log here ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup UIBackgroundModes inside Info.plist to fetch data in background

```
    <key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
    <array>
      <string>fetch</string>   
    </array>
```